# bibtex: original author, contemporary editor

Tags: bibtex

Important old books frequently come out in different, competing editions with different editors. Is there no way to make both author and editor explicit in bibtex?

For instance, the following book

[https://www.amazon.com/Middlemarch-Penguin-Classics-George-Eliot/dp/0141439548?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-d-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=0141439548](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0141439548)

shows both author and editor on the title page:

> George Eliot
>
> Middlemarch
>
> Edited with an Introduction and Notes by
>
> Rosemary Ashton.

The following bibtex entry lists George Eliot and Rosemary Ashton as co-authors, which is not accurate.  Also, it would not make sense for this to be an `@incollection`.

```
@Book{EliotGeorgeAshtonRosemary1994MiddlemarchISBN978_0_141_43954_9,
   author = {
           Eliot, George
                   and
                   Ashton, Rosemary
   }
   , title = {
           Middlemarch
      }
   , publisher = {
           Penguin
   }
   , address =  {
London
   }
   , year = {
           1994
   }
   , isbn = {
978-0-141-43954-9
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `biblatex` defines these fields: `annotator, commentator, introduction, foreword, afterword`. Maybe you can consider using it?

Comment: The `editor` field would be more appropriate for such cases,  if allowed for books; it is quite common in the humanities! - I can live with the warning, but think it is unfortunate that most bibstyles do not show the editor.

Comment: Not just the humanities!  See e.g. [*Probability Theory: The Language of Science*, author E.T. Jaynes, editor G. Larry Bretthorst](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/probability-theory-logic-science?format=HB), or [*The Mathematical Theory of Probability and Statistics*, author: Richard von Mises, "edited and complemented by": Hilda Geiringer](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Theory-Probability-Statistics-Richard/dp/1483255387/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1607624780&sr=1-9).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the note field. All BiBTeX styles I know of include this field in the output. If `test.bib` consists of the entry

```
@Book{EliotGeorgeAshtonRosemary1994MiddlemarchISBN978_0_141_43954_9,
   author    = {Eliot, George},
   note      = {Edited by Rosemary Ashton},
   title     = {Middlemarch},
   publisher = {Penguin},
   address   = {London},
   year      = {1994},
   isbn      = {978-0-141-43954-9}
}
```

then the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

results (via latex-bibtex-latex-latex) in the output

[image]